# Limits on number of unique IconStyle url for KML File

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using KML files with Google Maps to display property locations.  Ideally I want all street numbers associated with the properties to display on the map.  I understand KML "Labels" are not supported in Google Maps.

As a "hack" I made a webserver which serves a small png containing the street number as a graphic.  Example: http://example.com/getstreetmarker296.png  would return a small graphic with the number "296":

[image]

In my KML file I then reference this url as the IconStyle:

```
<Placemark>
  <description>296 PARKS STREET</description>
  <Style><IconStyle><Icon>
  <href>http://example.com/getstreetmarker296.png</href></Icon>
  </IconStyle></Style>
  <Point>
  <coordinates>-70.xxxx,42.xxxx,0</coordinates>  
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

This works for about the first 50 or street numbers.  But the majority of my points show the default blue map marker:

[image]

In the image above, the green arrows correspond to the street number markers made to my server.

I checked the log of my webserver and see there were about 50-60 calls made.

Is there a limit on the number of unique IconStyle urls that can be referenced?

Comment: Yes.  It is time based, to reduce latency in serving the tiles, Google will only render so many custom icons.  You could try using a third party KML renderer, but the latency will still be there.

Comment: Do you know of another approach?  All I want to do is display street numbers associated with these points.  Seems like this should be simple...  I guess another approach is to use markers.  But not sure if this could lead to performance issues.

Comment: Have you tried KMZ (compressed KML, including attached images) approach. In this case Google will need only one request to download compressed file to their server and all images will be uploaded with a KMZ.

Comment: @xomena - thanks - will have to give this a try.

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm running into this problem as well.